# Laravel 5.2 Pass Middleware Param to Register Service Container in Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seem to have a circular dependency where we have a service provider that registers an object with the service container, and boots a config file and some middleware, but the middleware now needs to be passed a param parsed from requests JWT token to the service container prior to it being instantiated, as well as the guard of the user since the service provider needs to be able to get the authenticated user and there are 5 different types (Applicant, Manager, Admin, etc) so the guard is needed to Auth::guard($guard)->getUser() within the constructor since it defaults to the Applicant if null like Auth::guard()->getUser().

How do you work around something like this?  If it helps I'm using tymons/JWTAuth (develop) branch to make use of Laravel's guard API.

1. Should I refactor and just bind to the service container directly within the middleware and not use a service provider at all so I can use the parameter to instantiate the service container object, and the guard.  Seems like the only likely solution, but before I refactor all of this I wanted to ask if there was a better way.
2. Can I use two service providers?  One that adds middleware, and a deferred one that will somehow eventually register an object with the service container??? If so how would you pass the parameter in a config?  Thinking this isn't possible based on what I know.

Adding a setter to the object isn't an option to prevent anyone accidentally invoking it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `tymon/jwt-auth`?  If so, your service provider could set up an event listener that fires when the token is decoded.  Something like:

```
event()->listen('tymon.jwt.valid', function($user){
  app()->singleton(YourInterface::class, function() use ($user){
    //this will only register once your token is decoded
  }
});
```

You could still listen for an event if you aren't using this package, then bind once that fires.  This is basically the same as your option 1, but at least it keeps the code organized where you want it.

Comment: I am using `tymon/jwt-auth`.  So the event binding you're adding is in boot of the service provider?  Is it better to use `event()->listen` or `$this->app['Event']->listen` is it just preference?  Will try this out right now.

Comment: Yea there are a few syntaxes for binding events you can use, they should both work. You could also create a listener and put it into the array in EventServiceProvider

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I can't seem to get this to work.  Searching through `tymon/jwt-auth` it seems the event `tymon.jwt.valid` doesn't exist.  I'm using the `develop` branch so I can use JWTGuard so trying to find something comparable.  I also need to get the provider set on the middleware so user in the case of `auth:user` I'm hoping I can just access this using `getProvider`

Comment: It should exist: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication#middleware-and-filters

Comment: @mtpultz you can add another middleware or copy the existing one to add your own custom event.

Comment: Seems like the wiki reference is for Laravel 4.x, but definitely not in the 1.0 pseudo-stable development branch.

Comment: The next section of the wiki for 5.x says it has the same events as above. I haven't been through the source code though so can't confirm. Either way, I think binding in an event listener is the route you want to take. Hope it helps!

Comment: I temporarily commented out the boot, deferred the service provider, added the middleware manually, and set config entry per request to store the user ID and guard so I can invoke Auth::guard($guard)->getUser() in the service container when it instantiates

Comment: k I'll have a look at binding our own event, since the listener doesn't appear to work.  Thanks for the help :)